# Pivot SQL by Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Well, there's a lot of references for pivot SQL. But still, I couldn't solve my problem.

I have the following table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
InspectYear     PartNo    PartDesc    A       B      C     D
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2015            001       Part 1      9       8      8     6
2015            002       Part 2      8       8      8     6
2014            001       Part 1      9       2      8     6
2014            002       Part 2      8       8      8     4
```

I want to have the following result with dynamic "`InspectYear`":

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
PartNo    PartDesc  NewCol        2014    2015
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
001       Part 1    A             9       9
001       Part 1    B             2       8
001       Part 1    C             8       8
001       Part 1    D             6       6
002       Part 2    A             8       8
002       Part 2    B             8       8
002       Part 2    C             8       8
002       Part 2    D             4       6
```

Does anyone have an idea for the pivot query?
really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below dynamic PIVOT:

```
DECLARE @InspectYear AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@Query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @InspectYear = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(InspectYear) 
            FROM table4 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @Query = 
';WITH data AS
(
    SELECT InspectYear, PartNo, PartDesc, NewCol, number
    FROM table4
    UNPIVOT
    (
      number
      FOR NewCol IN (A, B, C,D)
    ) AS unpvt
)
SELECT *
FROM data
PIVOT
(
    SUM(number)
    FOR InspectYear IN ( '+@InspectYear+' )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY PartNo, PartDesc, NewCol '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

**Note:** Please refer @doraemon Create table and insert data statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to `UNPIVOT` your initial data and then again `PIVOT` it.

Here is the solution I found. See if this meet your requirement.

```
CREATE TABLE table4
(
    InspectYear INT,
    PartNo VARCHAR(5),
    PartDesc VARCHAR(30),
    A INT,
    B INT,
    C INT,
    D INT
)

INSERT INTO table4 VALUES
(2015, '001', 'Part 1', 9, 8, 8, 6),
(2015, '002', 'Part 2', 8, 8, 8, 6),
(2014, '001', 'Part 1', 9, 2, 8, 6),
(2014, '002', 'Part 2', 8, 8, 8, 4)

;WITH data AS
(
    SELECT InspectYear, PartNo, PartDesc, NewCol, number
    FROM table4
    UNPIVOT
    (
      number
      FOR NewCol IN (A, B, C,D)
    ) AS unpvt
)
SELECT *
FROM data
PIVOT
(
    SUM(number)
    FOR InspectYear IN ( [2014], [2015] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY PartNo, PartDesc, NewCol
```

Please have a try. Thank you. :)

Comment: perfect one solution

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. But this one is static pivot. I need the dynamic one.. 'cause the 'InspectYear' field is always added.